# Android Multi-Touch ACTION_POINTER_UP MotionEvent.getX IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, multi-touch, touch-event, motionevent

Currently I am working on a game that implements Android multi-touch by overriding the `onTouchEvent` method. In it I have a for loop going over all of the pointers. However, sometimes on `ACTION_POINTER_UP` this fails to work correctly and throws an `IllegalArgumentException`. I tried to catch it and continue my loop but it sometimes doesn't work and displays erratic behaviour. I have debugged to make sure when the `IllegalArgumentException` was thrown the looped pointer was not the active pointer nor was it greater or equal to the total number of pointers. Here's my code for reference.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            return true;
        }
        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            return false;
        }
        boolean notUp = true;
        int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
        boolean p1Turned = false;
        boolean p2Turned = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < pointerCount; ++i) {
            float x, y;
            if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP && event.getActionIndex() == i){
                notUp = false;
                continue;
            }
            try {
                x = event.getX(event.getPointerId(i));
                y = D.height - event.getY(event.getPointerId(i));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                continue;
            }
            //test if the pointer is touching a button
            if (x >= buttons[0] && x <= buttons[6] && y <= buttons[1] && y >= buttons[7]) {
                p1.turnLeft();
                p1Turned = true;
            } else if (x >= buttons[12] && x <= buttons[12 + 6] && y <= buttons[12 + 1] && y >= buttons[12 + 7]) {
                p1.turnRight();
                p1Turned = true;
            } else if (x >= buttons[24] && x <= buttons[24 + 6] && y <= buttons[24 + 1] && y >= buttons[24 + 7]) {
                p2.turnLeft();
                p2Turned = true;
            } else if (x >= buttons[36] && x <= buttons[36 + 6] && y <= buttons[36 + 1] && y >= buttons[36 + 7]) {
                p2.turnRight();
                p2Turned = true;
            }
        }
        if (!p1Turned) {
            p1.stopTurning();
        }
        if (!p2Turned) {
            p2.stopTurning();
        }
        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            p1.stopTurning();
            p2.stopTurning();
        }
        return notUp;
    }
```

When the glitch occurs it's always ACTION_POINTER_UP and through debugging I found when the issue occurs `event.getActionIndex()` is always 0, however when i = 1 and `event.getX(event.getPointerId(i))` is called it throws an `IllegalArgumentException` and the loop is skipped over a second time. The number of active pointers is always 2 when this situation occurs so no code in the for block gets called.

Any help regarding the situation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, event.getX() takes in the index, not the ID. See this for more reference: [Android/Processing MotionEvent getX() raises exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744427/android-processing-motionevent-getx-raises-exception)